# Генератор: вывести сперва первые пары затем последние из вложенных списков

Tags: python

У меня есть список, состоящий из списков с числами. Каждый внутренний список имеет длину 4.
Например:

```
list_with_ids = [[123, 234, 345, 456], [678, 890, 901, 1001], [2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],]
```

Как сделать генератор, выдающий числа из внутренних списков следующим образом:

```
123->234->678->890->2000->3000->345->456->901->1001->4000->5000
```

Т.е. сперва выдаются поочередно числа из внутренних списков с индексами 0 и 1, затем, когда они закончатся, аналогичным образом числа с индексами 2 и 3
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в лоб решать, то как-то так можно:

```
def myGenerator(list):
    for el in list:
        yield el[0]
        yield el[1]
    for el in list:
        yield el[2]
        yield el[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain 
from operator import itemgetter

g = chain(map(itemgetter(0, 1), lst),
          map(itemgetter(-2, -1), lst))
```